# OnDocumentComplete doesn't fire on component

Tags: delphi

If I use the following component on a form `WebBrowser1: TMyWebBrowser;`, and if I put on the form `OnDocumentComplete = WebBrowser1DocumentComplete`, the `TMyWebBrowser.DocumentComplete` doesn't fire even if `WebBrowser1DocumentComplete` procedure is empty.

The only way I can fire the `TMyWebBrowser.DocumentComplete` is having `OnDocumentComplete = nil`.

Anybody can explain me why?
Thanks
Sam

```
type
  TMyWebBrowser = class(TWebBrowser)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
      const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Completed: Boolean;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure NavigateUntilCompleted(URL: String);
  published
    { Published declarations }
  End;

procedure Register;

implementation


procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Sam', [TMyWebBrowser]);
end;

constructor TMyWebBrowser.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  onDocumentComplete := DocumentComplete;
end;

procedure TMyWebBrowser.DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
      const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
    begin
      // check that the event is raised for the top-level browser (not frames or iframes)
      if pDisp = TMyWebBrowser(ASender).ControlInterface then
      begin
        Completed := TRUE;
      end;
      inherited;
    end;
```

Comment: OT: I would personally override the `InvokeEvent` method e.g. [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/m8HMzgtX).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign more than one method to an event, but you try to assign 2 and overwrite the first one.

Class definition

```
constructor TMyWebBrowser.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  // set OnDocumentComplete event
  onDocumentComplete := DocumentComplete;
end;
```

and in your code

```
var
  LMyWebBrowser : TMyWebBrowser;
begin
  LMyWebBrowser := TMyWebBrowser.Create( nil );
  // now overwriting the value set by constructor 
  LMyWebBrowser.onDocumentComplete := WebBrowser1Complete;
end;
```

You can check by yourself with

```
var
  LMyWebBrowser : TMyWebBrowser;
begin
  LMyWebBrowser := TMyWebBrowser.Create( nil );
  // check
  if Assigned( LMyWebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete ) then
    ShowMessage( 'OnDocumentComplete is already set!' );
end;
```